# How can I create a web site that can execute user code

Tags: api, rest, cloud, openstack, serverless

I need to create a `webapp` that can **execute user code**, something similar to firebase cloud function, but I don't want it to be that much powerful.

For example if the user creates a script like:

```
{A,B} = getinput();
return A + B
```

And start running this script.
Whenever user sends a request with a **parameter** eg. `4,5` it returns a **response** with `9`. I want this to be running till the user stops it. I have started messing around with the cloud platforms and `openstack` etc., but I couldn't see a proper path towards it.

Most of sources I end up, explains about how I can create `api server` for myself, but I want something where anyone with an account can define how their request are processed.

Can someone recommend a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is not directly related to OpenStack. In case that you want to use such kind of web applications, please have a look at OpenFaaS, which try to mimic the way AWS Lambda does. It is also similar to Firebase Cloud Functions.